# Can Template Haskell generate multi-param typeclass instances?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

The latest (2.8.0.0) definition for the `Dec` has the following instance constructor:

```
InstanceD Cxt Type [Dec]
```

Seems that only one type can be instantiated. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, multi-parameter type classes are supported.

Somewhat confusingly, **the `Type` argument refers to the entire instance head**, and, even though it's not really a type, it looks enough like one syntactically that the type `Type` was reused for this purpose.

Therefore, if you're generating a multi-parameter `instance Foo Int Bool`, you need to use the "type" `Foo Int Bool`, constructed for example like this:

```
(ConT (mkName "Foo") `AppT` ConT (mkName "Int")) `AppT` ConT (mkName "Bool")
```

Here's a complete example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TemplateHaskell #-}

import Language.Haskell.TH

class Foo a b where
  foo :: (a, b)

$(return [InstanceD [] (((ConT (mkName "Foo")) `AppT` ConT (mkName "Int")) `AppT` ConT (mkName "Bool"))
   [ValD (VarP (mkName "foo")) 
         (NormalB (TupE [LitE (IntegerL 42), ConE (mkName "False")])) []]])

main = print (foo :: (Int, Bool))
```

Answer (score 7):

An easy way to answer this and similar is to use `runQ` with spliced definitions. Eg in ghci:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set -XTemplateHaskell
Prelude> :set -XMultiParamTypeClasses 
Prelude> import Language.Haskell.TH
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> class Class a b where
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> runQ [d| instance Class Int Bool where |]
[InstanceD [] (AppT (AppT (ConT :Interactive.Class) (ConT GHC.Types.Int)) (ConT GHC.Types.Bool)) []]
```

This shows the exact form needed, replace `Class` with whatever class you are using.